# Trying to store text entered into entry widget to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, variables, tkinter

I am trying to store the user's input in the "`nEnt`" entry widget as a variable that will be printed later on.

I've tried `.get()` but when I run the program it doesn't print the name it prints a blank line and then it starts the game, I think it might be printing what is there in the beginning rather than what is the entry widget as the enter button is pressed.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
def game():
    while 1:
        c1 = input("Would you like to play from the beginning?").lower()
        if c1 == "yes":
            lvl1()
        elif c1 == "no":
            print("Your score was:", score)
            break
        else:
            game()
    quit()
def lvl1():
    print(name)
    print("LEVEL 1")
    global score
    score = 0
    operators = ("+","-")
    while 1:
        No1 = random.randint(1,10)
        No2 = random.randint(1,10)
        Op = random.choice(operators)
        if Op == "+":
            A1 = No1 + No2
            print("What is", No1, Op, No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        elif Op == "-":
            A1 = No1 - No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        if answer == A1:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("Incorrect! Try again...")
            game()
        if score == 5:
            break
    print("Congratulations on making it to level 2!")
    lvl2()
def lvl2():
    print("LEVEL 2")
    global score
    score = 5
    operators = ("+","-","x")
    while 1:
        No1 = random.randint(1,15)
        No2 = random.randint(1,15)
        Op = random.choice(operators)
        if Op == "+":
            A1 = No1 + No2
            print("What is", No1, Op, No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        elif Op == "-":
            A1 = No1 - No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        else:
            A1 = No1 * No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        if answer == A1:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("Incorrect! Try again...")
            game()
        if score == 10:
            break
    print("Congratulations on making it to level 3!")
    lvl3()
def lvl3():
    print("LEVEL 3")
    global score
    score = 10
    operators = ("+","-","x")
    while 1:
        No1 = random.randint(10,50)
        No2 = random.randint(10,50)
        Op = random.choice(operators)
        if Op == "+":
            A1 = No1 + No2
            print("What is", No1, Op, No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        elif Op == "-":
            A1 = No1 - No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        else:
            A1 = No1 * No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        if answer == A1:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("Incorrect! Try again...")
            game()
        if score == 15:
            break
    print("Congratulations on making it to level 4!")
    lvl4()
def lvl4():
    print("LEVEL 4")
    global score
    score = 15
    operators = ("+","-","x")
    while 1:
        No1 = random.randint(10,100)
        No2 = random.randint(10,100)
        Op = random.choice(operators)
        if Op == "+":
            A1 = No1 + No2
            print("What is", No1, Op, No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        elif Op == "-":
            A1 = No1 - No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        else:
            A1 = No1 * No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        if answer == A1:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("Incorrect! Try again...")
            game()
        if score == 20:
            break
    print("Congratulations! You have completed the game.")

def nextstep():
    y.destroy()
    nLabel.destroy()
    nEnt.destroy()
    nBtn.destroy()
    w = Label(topFrame, text="To play the game press Start", fg="black")
    w.pack(fill=X and Y)
    button1 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Start", fg="black", command=lvl1)
    button1.pack()




root = Tk()
root.title("Maths Game!")
topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
y = Label(topFrame, text="Welcome to the maths game.")
y.pack(fill=X and Y)
nLabel = Label(bottomFrame, text="Enter your name below.")
nLabel.pack(fill=X and Y)
nEnt = Entry(bottomFrame)
nEnt.pack()
name = (nEnt).get()
nBtn = Button(bottomFrame, text="Enter", command=nextstep)
nBtn.pack()
name = nEnt.get()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are evaluating the contents of `nEnt` to populate `name` once at the start of the program. At the start of the program, no text has been entered in to the entry field. You need to get the contents of the entry field perhaps in the `nextstep` function after the user has pressed the "Enter" button.

Answer (score 1):

- You should redesign your entire application before coding anything.
- There are issues other than the one you mentioned.
- I am going to address only the issue you highlighted.

Solution:

1. You have to get the user input related to his name within the callback of `nBtn`.
2. You have to declare name as being a global variable within each individual function that uses.

Putting the solution in practice (with your own actual code which needs to be redesigned and cleaned):

```
from tkinter import *
import random
def game():
    while 1:
        c1 = input("Would you like to play from the beginning?").lower()
        if c1 == "yes":
            lvl1()
        elif c1 == "no":
            print("Your score was:", score)
            break
        else:
            game()
    quit()
def lvl1():
    global name
    print(name)
    print("LEVEL 1")
    global score
    score = 0
    operators = ("+","-")
    while 1:
        No1 = random.randint(1,10)
        No2 = random.randint(1,10)
        Op = random.choice(operators)
        if Op == "+":
            A1 = No1 + No2
            print("What is", No1, Op, No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        elif Op == "-":
            A1 = No1 - No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        if answer == A1:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("Incorrect! Try again...")
            game()
        if score == 5:
            break
    print("Congratulations on making it to level 2!")
    lvl2()
def lvl2():
    print("LEVEL 2")
    global score
    score = 5
    operators = ("+","-","x")
    while 1:
        No1 = random.randint(1,15)
        No2 = random.randint(1,15)
        Op = random.choice(operators)
        if Op == "+":
            A1 = No1 + No2
            print("What is", No1, Op, No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        elif Op == "-":
            A1 = No1 - No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        else:
            A1 = No1 * No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        if answer == A1:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("Incorrect! Try again...")
            game()
        if score == 10:
            break
    print("Congratulations on making it to level 3!")
    lvl3()
def lvl3():
    print("LEVEL 3")
    global score
    score = 10
    operators = ("+","-","x")
    while 1:
        No1 = random.randint(10,50)
        No2 = random.randint(10,50)
        Op = random.choice(operators)
        if Op == "+":
            A1 = No1 + No2
            print("What is", No1, Op, No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        elif Op == "-":
            A1 = No1 - No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        else:
            A1 = No1 * No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        if answer == A1:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("Incorrect! Try again...")
            game()
        if score == 15:
            break
    print("Congratulations on making it to level 4!")
    lvl4()
def lvl4():
    print("LEVEL 4")
    global score
    score = 15
    operators = ("+","-","x")
    while 1:
        No1 = random.randint(10,100)
        No2 = random.randint(10,100)
        Op = random.choice(operators)
        if Op == "+":
            A1 = No1 + No2
            print("What is", No1, Op, No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        elif Op == "-":
            A1 = No1 - No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        else:
            A1 = No1 * No2
            print("What is", No1,Op,No2,"?")
            answer = float(input("Enter your answer"))
        if answer == A1:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("Incorrect! Try again...")
            game()
        if score == 20:
            break
    print("Congratulations! You have completed the game.")

def nextstep():
    global name
    name = nEnt.get()
    y.destroy()
    nLabel.destroy()
    nEnt.destroy()
    nBtn.destroy()
    w = Label(topFrame, text="To play the game press Start", fg="black")
    w.pack(fill=X and Y)
    button1 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Start", fg="black", command=lvl1)
    button1.pack()




root = Tk()
root.title("Maths Game!")
topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
y = Label(topFrame, text="Welcome to the maths game.")
y.pack(fill=X and Y)
nLabel = Label(bottomFrame, text="Enter your name below.")
nLabel.pack(fill=X and Y)
nEnt = Entry(bottomFrame)
nEnt.pack()
name = nEnt.get()
#name = (nEnt).get()
nBtn = Button(bottomFrame, text="Enter", command=nextstep)
nBtn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```